# Mobile Versoin Line Breaks Not Working

Tags: html, css, mobile

At: http://www.fmancoding.com their is a section under "featured game of the week" that displays all the games, then the title and description of it. It looks exactly what I would like it to, except on a mobile device. On a mobile device the images are being tabbed in and touching each other.
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have breaks inbetween each div and I believe div's automatically are created on a new line, like a paragraph. Also, I added padding and margin to see if this would fix the problem, but it did not.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Fman Coding</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center id="headerBox">
            <h1 id="header">Welcome To Fman Coding</h1>
            <h2 id="header">Most Games Are Mobile Friendly, And Can Be Used Offline!</h2>
        </center>
        <div id="MG">
            <div id="FG">
                <p id="ft">This Week's Featured Game!</p>
                <a href="Games/Miji.html"><img src="Games/Murderer.jpeg" width="100%" height="30%" alt="Miji"></a>
                <!-- Game Name & Description -->
                <p id="FGD">Miji! Input Your Number Of Players And It Will Automatically Generate Everyone's Job!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="gLibrary">
                <!-- Games -->
                <div id="gameFrame"><a href="Games/Miji.html"><img id="float" src="Games/Murderer.jpeg" width="15%" height="15%"></a><br/>
                    <h4 id="gameTitle">Miji</h4>
                    <span id="desc">This game auto selects your positions based on the number of people playing!</span>
                </div>
                <!-- Next Game -->
                <br/>
                <!-- Next Game -->
                <div id="gameFrame"><a href="Games/RPS.html"><img id="float" src="Games/RPS.jpg" width="15%" height="15%"></a><br/>
                    <h4 id="gameTitle">Rock, Paper, Scissors</h4>
                    <span id="desc">You can play Rock, Paper, Scissors, Shoot against a computer!</span>
                </div>
                <!-- Next Game -->
                <br/>
                <!-- Next Game -->
                <div id="gameFrame"><a href="MC/index.html"><img id="float" src="MC/Click.jpg" width="15%" height="15%"></a><br/>
                    <h4 id="gameTitle">Minecraft Player Finder</h4>
                    <span id="desc">Create groups for certain games and find players to play, or help you build stuff!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    text-align: center;
    color: aqua;
}
#headerBox{
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url('matrixCode.jpeg');
}
#gLibrary{
    color: #989898;
    margin: 15px;
    display: inline;
}
#gLibrary p a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aqua;
    display: inline;
}
#FG{
    border: 3px gold solid;
}
#FGD{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
#MG{
    border: 1px purple solid;
    background-color: #333;
}
#ft{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: red;
}
#gameTitle{
    color: aqua;
}
#float{
    float: left;
}
#desc{
    color: crimson;
}
#gameFrame{
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just found out this [solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/line-breaks-not-working-on-mobile/) in wordpress by Tobiasbg.

The cause for this basically is that your theme is hiding all 
 HTML tags (using display: none;) in it’s CSS file.

You can either correct it in the theme's CSS file or  give ,

```
br{
   display:block !important;
}
```

if you want only specific div's br to be shown give the div's class name prior to br in thre above code.

Answer (score 0):

`#gLibrary` should be displayed as block, not `inline` :

```
#gLibrary{
    color: #989898;
    margin: 15px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't fix the problem